# ChoronoForms v5 dropdown field dynamic preselection

Tags: forms, chronoforms

My question is a very simple question:

I want to preselect the single data stored in a previous form in a dropdown field of a form (chronoforms v5).

In other words: In the previous form user has chosen `'New York'` from a `cities` dropdown field.
Next time **the** user enters in the form he has to see the dropdown field positioned to the city of `'New York'`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your users are registered and logged in them you can save the User ID and the selected value to a database table in the first form; then in the second form use a DB Read action in the On Load event to recover the saved value.